# Jenkins - Role based authentication - Sing up with default role

Tags: jenkins

I am setting up a Jenkins instance to run static-code-analysis for many projects. Each projects, on their own, create their code-analysis-jobs with their SCM and branches. I have the [Role Strategy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin) plugin installed but struck configuring the system with the below criteria.

- The project leads should be able to signup the Jenkins and create/view/modify/run the jobs they only created. (Is it possible for this lead-role user to create user of developer role?)
- The developers can view/build the jobs which they have privileges.
- The project leads can assign the developers with jobs they can view/run.

How to do this, if at all possible? If not, how other ways you all do it considering the Jenkins to allow users signup, create/manage/run only their jobs (securing the jobs from other users)? (Also, the signed user should not be allowed to administer the Jenkins)

EDIT-1: I have an admin role (myself) user who has the all privileges to configure the system, but the admin to perform the role assignment of every user who signup.

Comment: That sounds very complicated. Is it really necessary to have so much structure? Why not give developers all privileges and have a couple of administrator users? It will be much simpler for you

Comment: Okay, so, how do you manage the users and roles? Can you answer the 2nd question?

Answer (score -1):

The [Role Strategy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin) should suffice your request.

It even has regex pattern based setting where a user can only see certain projects.

I have been using this plugin extensively and its really helpful.

Comment: Would you please elaborate your answer and show me some configuration to achieve this? I couldnt make out much from the document page.